# Как остановить анимацию на последнем кадре css3

Tags: css3

При клике выпадает окно, окно вылетает, но потом опять заходит на место,

```
@keyframes blocks-main {
0%{
top: -625px;
}
40%{
top: -625px;
}
70%{
top: -625px;
}
100%{
top: 0;
}
}
```

настройки анимации

```
animation: blocks-main .5s;
```

Анимация проигрывает 1 раз, доходит до 100% и опять на ноль, и блок уходит, потому что `top:-625px;` Как сделать, чтобы анимация остановилась на 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидный способ:

В css:

```
blocks-main-visible{top:0};
```

В обработчик клика:

```
this.className='ваш_класс_с_анимацией blocks-main-visible'
```

Возможно есть еще способы.

Answer (score 4):

```
@keyframes blocks-main { 
    0%{ top: -625px; }
    40%{ top: -625px; }
    70%{ top: -625px; }
    100%{ top: 0; }
}

div {
    animation: blocks-main .5s;
}
```

в конец добавь: **forwards**

```
div {
    animation: blocks-main .5s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
```